# detecting a plateu in sensor measurements

Tags: algorithm, filtering

I have a stream of data measurements with an initial increasing phase that is followed by a plateau.  The measurements are noisy without clear bound.  I would like to stop ingesting the stream when the plateau is detected:

```
while (not_const)
{
    add_measurement( stream.get() );
    not_const = !is_const();
}
```

Is there a well-known algorithm for dealing with such problem? I know about Kalman-Filters, but not so sure if they are specifically made for this.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91066/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kalman filter will cover your noise, so long as the *variance* is calculable.  Yes, it can help in this situation.  Depending on your application, you may find that the first derivative of a moving average will do as well for you.  Kalman merely optimizes some linear parameters to give a "best" prediction of actual (vs observed-through-noise) values.

You still need to handle your interpretation of that prediction series.  You need to define what constitutes a "plateau".  How close to 0 do you need the computable slope?  Does that figure depend on the preceding input?  How abrupt is the transition between the increase and the plateau?  The latter considerations would suggest looking at the second derivative as well: a quick-change detector of some ilk.